# Estimating Expected Convergence Time for Random Walk in Combined Expander Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, random-walk, stopping-times

I currently have two identical [expander graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expander_graph), each with $n$ vertices, and each vertex has a degree of $d$, where d is a constant. Now, I connect these two expander graphs with a path of length $n$. I want to perform a random walk on this graph. What is the expected convergence time?

**Initial state:** The starting point is in one of the expander graphs, and the endpoint is in the other expander graph.

**Random walk strategy:** Randomly select a neighbor and move to that neighbor's location until reaching the endpoint.

**My Attempt:** While it is well-known that random walk convergence time is typically within $O(\log n)$ on expander graph, I am struggling to determine whether this property can be leveraged to calculate the expected convergence time in this specific scenario.

Thank you very much for all the suggestions and assistance provided.

Comment: By "convergence time", do you mean "hitting time"? I'm not familiar with this concept.

Comment: @abacaba Exactly "the first hitting time".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i have found the answer.

Theorem 4 in [Aleliunas 1979](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4568017) states that the expected first hitting time of starting from $x$ to $y$ in connected graph $G$ is bounded by $n^3$, where n is the number of vertices.